# Concatenar componentes bower con gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

Buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo un problema al intentar concatenar todos mis componentes de bower en un archivo unico llamado vendor.js.

Esta es mi tarea de gulp:

```
gulp.task('bower', function() {
    var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', {
        restore: true
    })
    var cssFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.css', {
        restore: true
    })
    return gulp.src(bower(), {
            base: 'bower_components'
        })
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(order([
            "bower_components/jquery/**/*.js",
            "bower_components/angular/**/*.js",
            "bower_components/moment/**/*.js",
            "bower_components/**/*.js"
        ], {
            base: './'
        }))
        /*.pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))*/
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.js))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.css))
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
            if (~path.dirname.indexOf('fonts')) {
                path.dirname = '/fonts'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.vendor))
})
```

Al ejecutar recibo el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Para solventar el error como veis, en la linea comentada he intentado portar a ES5 con babel, pero si no es un error me arroja otro.

¿Como conseguís aunar todos los componentes en un archivo css y js sin que arroje errores? ¿Es esto una locura? Mi objetivo es no tener que incluir todos y cada unos de los componentes de bower a mano.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que tu problema esta en la parte donde defines tus require, es decir para usar un plugin de gulp, gulp debe estar instalado y tambien el plugin, sino te esta detectando el require es por que o bien te falto algo en su sintaxis o no tienes instalado gulp o algun plugin del mismo, te recomiendo que edites y pongas todo tu gulpfile.js